# How to get the application font color in Qt

Tags: qt, fonts, qt4, symbian, nokia

I want to put some text on my UI.

I am drawing the text in a paint event of a widget using  painter.

Here is the sample code, which shows how I am drawing the text:

```
QWidget::paintEvent(painter);
QPainter paint(this);
paint.drawText(QPoint(10,30),"Duplex");
```

However, the text color looks like the default theme color. How do I set the application font color to the text in a paint event?

Answer (score 12):

here is the answer i got it

```
 QPen pen  = (QApplication::palette().text().color());

 paint.setPen(pen);
```

Comment: This is THE answer, but in addition to this, if you are in a paint event  the unedited painter.pen() color should be the default color as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the 
`QPainter::setBrush(QBrush &)` and `QPainter::setPen(QPen &)` methods to change the color used to draw graphics (and incidently the text color).

The command `paint.setPen(QPen(QColor(255,0,0))` will set the outline color to red and `paint.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0,255,0))` will set the fill color to green.

You can also use directly the `QPainter::setPen(QColor &)` methods to change the color of the outline.

Comment: Thanks, lohrun..
infact i wanted how to take the default text color.. i got the answer too.. i will place it